# How to add storybook stories directories in several frontends?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

we want to integrate Storybook components for our project in several directories but access all of them via the settings made in .storybook/main.js

Right now we use the workaround to out-comment the part of the main.js config which is not needed, but obviously this is not a longterm solution.

Looks like this then:

```
module.exports = {
stories: [
    // TODO: make all stories visible at the same time

    // --- GPF components ---
    "../../../apps/frontend/src/components/stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../../../apps/frontend/src/components/stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",

    // // --- UTR components ---
    // "../../../apps/utr-frontend/components/stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    // "../../../apps/utr-frontend/components/stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",

    // // --- Global components ---
    // "../../components/stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    // "../../components/stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
],
addons: ["@storybook/addon-links", "@storybook/addon-essentials"],};
```

Any suggestions how to do it i a propper way?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so stupid me, I forgot to change the titles of the single components:

```
import React from "react";
import { action } from "@storybook/addon-actions";

import Button from "../lib/button";

export default {
    title: "Global Button", // -- change title here! --
    component: Button,
};

export const Text = () => (
    <Button onClick={action("clicked")}>Global Button</Button>
);

export const Emoji = () => (
    <Button onClick={action("clicked")}>
        <span role='img' aria-label='so cool'>
               
        </span>
    </Button>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A glob pattern should solve this problem

```
  stories: ['../../**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)'],
```

Comment: wasn't the problem but thanks anyways for that quick help!! think it'll be the solution in 99% of the cases when other people search for this